# creating multiple .htaccess redirects

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I currently have a website that is redirecting from -

```
#-- Redirect http://www.mywebsite.com/en/index.php ---> http://www.mywebsite.com/
#Redirects
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

I need to add another condition for it to redirect from mywebsite.com ---> http://www.mywebsite.com/

Basically i need to add a statement to redirect non www users to force them into wwww.

How can i do this without both conditions and rules messing each other up?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

It is possible not to mention mywebsite.com at all, just to check the starting www and use backreference for the domain (did not check the rule).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```